# Inserting data based on different conditons

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Though , i put my efforts in making question easy to understand , but i still dnt know whats going wrong . Anyways , im trying to make it more compact

I have below table now only :

In column number JU means Junior and SU means Senior

```
 name         number            fin
------------------------------------
 paul        JU00011          100401
 paul        JU00012          100402
 paul        JU00012          100403
 maul        JU00021          100641
 maul        JU00022          100642
 paul        SU00012          100401
 paul        SU00012          100402
 paul        SU00012          100403

Now in this table , fin for paul are same ( for junior ans senior ).
i need to make an update in this table 
for example :If paul is coming under two numbers (i.e JU and SU) and have same fin number,
so i want to update fin , when 2 fin are same and belongs to same name and is coming under Junior category and Senior Category 

 Final Result :
name         number            fin
------------------------------------
 paul        JU00011          100401
 paul        JU00012          100402
 paul        JU00012          100403
 maul        JU00021          100641
 maul        JU00022          100642
 paul        SU00012          1004011
 paul        SU00012          1004012
 paul        SU00012          1004013

  Such type of records are more.
```

Comment: Why 20002 for paul?

Comment: Why `nvarchar(15)`? Can `id` really ever store Unicode data? `varchar(11)` would cover all possibilities for `int`. Why `nvarchar(1)`? Can `no` really every store Unicode data? Just use `char(1)` - or don't bother, since `RIGHT(no,1)` already implicitly casts the result as `varchar(1)`.

Comment: @Mihai - corrected

Comment: @AaronBertrand - ok..Well nvarchar was also working .. i will change it to char

Comment: @user21546 it works, just wasteful, not in any measurable way here, but why use space/memory you don't need to use? Anyway the requirements still seem to be a mess to me. Why is 1800 special? Because it's larger? Are there any other school ids? What are the rules when there is a school id 2100 too? Also you say "offset of 10" but 10,001 -> 100,011 is actually an offset of 90,010. Can you please get your story straight, and ask a coherent question that covers all potential edge cases?

Comment: @AaronBertrand i had already mentioned that there are only two school id ...i.e 800 and 1800..i again say..if same name is in two different school , then the select query should be like select (id as char) + (right[no],2) from TN inner join TM on TN.name=TM.name..but i cnt figure out how to use in same query

Comment: It's still not clear whether you want an offset of 10 or an offset of 90,010. We can solve real, specific problems, but it becomes very difficult when the words you use don't match the data you show.

Comment: hello , please see the corrected version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the way this question has changed, it is difficult to determine exactly what you need.  The current data and query in the question do not match the result you have posted.

That said, assuming the data is the way I think it is, this should provide the result you want

```
INSERT INTO T3 (name,number,fin)
SELECT 
    T1.name,
    T1.Rollno as number,
    CAST(CID AS NVARCHAR(11)) +
    CASE WHEN DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY T1.Name, T1.Unique_id ORDER BY Type) = 2 THEN N'1' ELSE N'' END +
    CAST(Right([Rollno], 1) AS NVARCHAR(1)) AS fin
FROM T1
INNER JOIN T2 ON T1.Unique_ID = T2.Unique_ID
```

Seriously though, I would put some effort into validating your data and reviewing your database design.

Answer (score 1):

this structure is incorrect, use M:N relationship with 3 Table

Student Table

```
StudentId       FirstName          LastName                
1               John               Sampo        
2               Ann                Rolls              
3               Martin             Blake
```

School Table

```
SchoolId        SchoolName
1               ABC Language School
2               Albany County
```

StudentSchool Tbale

```
SchoolId      StudentId         
2               1
2               2
1               3
```

and now use inner join for relational select

Comment: I  have corrected my question , please check